# Angular 2 Set begin value of select

Tags: typescript, angular

This is my select code :

```
   <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
       <option *ngFor="#p of prototypes" [value]="p.selector">
             {{ p.selectorName }}
       </option>
   </select>
```

How do I set a standard begin value to this `select option` I thought i have to set this variable:

```
 selectedPrototypeSelector: string;
```

To this:     `selectedPrototypeSelector: string = "Test";`

But the `"Test"` is not showing first in the select box The begin value is empty, how do I set this for example to: Select your option.

Here a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/UU3Pvw?p=preview) ,

as you can see the select box is empty while i set the value `p.selector` and the same for the second select where i give the value of `constraint`:

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="expression.constraint">
     <option *ngFor="#constraint of prototype.constraints" [value]="constraint">
         {{ constraint }}
     </option>
 </select>
```

I want to set the begin value of every select box to a static `string = "Select an option";`

Comment: What should be the default value? Where does it come from? A property on the component class or some static string value?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it is just a static string value I edited my question

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with `ngValue`

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
   <option *ngFor="let p of prototypes" [ngValue]="p">
         {{ p.id }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Just set `selectedPrototypeSelector` to the value you want to have selected.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oFADUI?p=preview)

Comment: It does not work here a plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/2soqqn?p=preview

It throws me this error: `EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known native property`

Comment: I can't reproduce but I also couldn't find `ngValue` being used. The error might be caused by using beta.14 instead of beta.15 (ngValue) was introduced very recently. (just change all `.14` to `.15` in `index.html`

Comment: Hmm it can not read the property [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/kUDkD9?p=preview

Comment: You need to move the code from the constructor to `ngOnInit()`. Inputs aren't yet  set when the constructor is executed. https://plnkr.co/edit/Q53Q9L?p=preview

Comment: That works only it throws errors for the `ngModelChange` I think it is a better plan to just set it like this: `this.selectedPrototypeSelector = "Select option";` how do I set that?

Comment: because i change the template depending on the `prototype.selector` How do i set it statically to `Select option`

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine, see [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yx6xc2pk7bOEd43xB70U?p=info). You either have non-string value in `p.selector` or it was typo -> `[value]="p.selectorName"`.

Comment: It was not a typo because both of them `p.selector` and `p.selectorName` are strings here you see the plunker link to get a better view: https://plnkr.co/edit/2soqqn?p=preview

Comment: you must initialize `selectedPrototypeSelector` but it is never assigned. see [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/m0kGpG3wQ4NEcrmb00yC?p=preview).

Comment: this works but i want to set it to a string value of "Select an option" take a look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ffT5b8?p=preview

Comment: Select can only show blank when nothing is selected or show selected option value if option is selected.  The only way is to add fake option with text "Select an option". check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36632069/491265.)

Comment: could you edit this in my plunker?

Comment: Because the second one is expression.constraint I tried it like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/zZrGsl?p=preview