# Drop down is not display in angular2 while page is loaded

Tags: html, typescript

I have the code for drop down it can't be display when page is loaded. 
    The  drop down is  display once clicked refresh button.

html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <select id="select111" name="role"  placeholder="Roles" class="form-control selectpicker" style="width:476px;">
       <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">{{role}}</option>
     </select>        
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
submitted = false;
loading= false;
// registrationForm: FormGroup;

 roles = ['User', 'Admin' ,'Supervisor'];

  registers={
   username:'',
         email:'',
         password:'',
         companyName:'',
         role:''
  }

    registervalid=false;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,public router:Router,public http:Http) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

         this.registers.role=this.roles[0];
    }

    onDefault($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    console.log('selected: ' + $event.target.value);

}    
   CreateAccount(){
     this.submitted = true;

   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   let body = JSON.stringify(this.registers);
   console.log('the registers is a' + body)
   this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/user', body,options).map((res:Response) => res.json())
   .subscribe( data =>{ 
   this.registers = data; 
   console.log(' data object' +JSON.stringify(data));
   if (data) {
   console.log('insert sucess msg' +JSON.stringify(this.registers));
        alert('login is successfully');
         this.router.navigate(['/login ']);
           }
},
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done')

   );
  }
}     



   `I used the angular2 here no controller all are components, In this file i wrote registration page for my application'.
```

The filed i added the drop for register person is enter with type as User or Admin or Supervisor, here i that drop down fields is not display when the registration page is loaded, it's show when we refresh already loaded page once again.

i attach the output images as follows:
[here the dropdown is not dsiplay after the companyName filed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fppqo.png)

And after i reload the page the dropdown is display (i.e) follows:
[the dropdown is comes after readload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Cth.png)

Comment: can you show your controller side code ? also you are missing `<` in `option` check it

Comment: Sry for < is missed but i already added in my code, i added the component code

Comment: your angular side is working fine, there must be error on css side, you need to inspect your code. and check whether code for dropdown exist in DOM or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the incorrect option element as per below:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<select id="select111" name="role"  placeholder="Roles" class="form-control selectpicker" style="width:476px;">
   <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">{{role}}</option>
 </select>
```

Also make sure the roles are being initialised in correctly in the controller typescript file.

See [Angular 2 - Setting selected value on dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968712/angular-2-setting-selected-value-on-dropdown-list)

Comment: all the code is fine drop down is comes when second time i load or reload the registration page