# Angular 4 setting selected option in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular

There are several questions about this and different answers but none of them really answers the question. So again:

Setting default of a Dropdown select by value isn't working in my case. Why?
This is from the dynamic Form tutorial of Angular 4:

```
<select [id]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key" [selected]="opt.selected">{{opt.selected+opt.value}}</option>
</select>
```

It doesn't select anything. Available options are:

- trueaaa
- falsebbb
- falseccc

But static true:

```
<option ... [selected]="true">...</option>
```

selects the last value (all true).
It also works with a private variable `boolvar = true` and using it in `[selected]="boolvar"`

I don't understand the difference between the "opt" object and the class variable.

Comment: try..... [selected]="opt.selected?true:false">

Comment: hey Gregor Please try [selected]="opt.selected == true" its work for me.

Comment: ! Holy **** ! It works! :D Thanks... a pity I still dont understand whats happening under the hood.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to select a value based on true / false use

```
[selected]="opt.selected == true"
```

for example:

```
<option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" 
    [value]="opt.key" 
    [selected]="opt.selected == true">
        {{opt.selected+opt.value}} 
</option>
```

checkit out

[Angular 2 - Setting selected value on dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968712/angular-2-setting-selected-value-on-dropdown-list)

Comment: Well... that works for me. 
Even if its dirty. As long as I dont understand whats happening under the hood, its the best solution for me.
Thy

Answer (score 23):

Here is my example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactMethod">Contact method</label>
    <select 
        name="contactMethod" 
        id="contactMethod" 
        class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="contact.contactMethod">
        <option *ngFor="let method of contactMethods" [value]="method.id">{{ method.label }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And in component you must get values from select:

```
contactMethods = [
    { id: 1, label: "Email" },
    { id: 2, label: "Phone" }
]
```

So, if you want select to have a default value selected (and proabbly you want that):

```
contact = {
    firstName: "CFR",
    comment: "No comment",
    subscribe: true,
    contactMethod: 2 // this id you'll send and get from backend
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to select a value as default, in your form builder give it a value :

```
this.myForm = this.FB.group({
    mySelect: [this.options[0].key, [/* Validators here */]]
});
```

Now in your HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select [formControlName]="mySelect">
        <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.key">ANY TEXT YOU WANT HERE</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

What my code does is giving your select a value, that is equal to the first value of your options list. This is how you select an option as default in Angular, selected is useless.

Answer (score 2):

To preselect an option when the form is initialized, the value of the select element must be set to an element attribute of the array you are iterating over and setting the value of option to. Which is the key attribute in this case.

From your example.

```
<select [id]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key">
  <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key"</option>
</select>
```

You are iterating over 'options' to create the select options. So the value of select must be set to the key attribute of an item in options(the one you want to display on initialization). This will display the default of select as the option whose value matches the value you set for select.

You can achieve this by setting the value of the select element in the onInit method like so.

```
ngOnInit(): void{
    myForm : new FormGroup({
       ...
       question.key : new FormControl(null)
    })
    // Get desired initial value to display on <select>
    desiredValue = question.options.find(opt => opt === initialValue)
    this.myForm.get(question.key).setValue(desiredValue.key)
}
```

Comment: How would I do with preselected values when I have a <select multiple> element?

Answer (score 0):

Remove [selected] from option tag:

```
<option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">
  {{opt.selected+opt.value}}
</option>
```

And in your form builder add:

```
key: this.question.options.filter(val => val.selected === true).map(data => data.key)
```