# How to use Arrays in Typescript in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have written a **Rest API** which returns set of data which are used to populate 2 drop-downs of a form.The returned data from the API are received from the Angular back-end and bound to the drop-downs. Instead of writing 2 Get requests to get data for 2 forms I try to get that data in one single Get.

Java Back-end Get method

```
 @GetMapping("/flight/formdata")
    public List getWebSiteFormData() {

        List formDataSet=FligthtDataServices.getWebSiteFormData();
        return formDataSet;
    }
```

Set of data displayed on Postman

```
[
    [
        "London Heathrow",
        "AP"
    ],
    [
        "Velana International Airport",
        "AP"
    ],
    [
        "Hamad International Airport",
        "AP"
    ],
    [
        "Suvarnabhumi Airport",
        "AP"
    ],
    [
        "Changi Airport",
        "AP"
    ],
    [
        "Business",
        "CL"
    ],
    [
        "Premium Economy",
        "CL"
    ],
    [
        "Economy",
        "CL"
    ]
]
```

Service class

```
  getWebSiteFormData():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/formdata`);
  }
```

My Approach is,
Data arrays who has value 'AP'  should be bind to Departure Airports drop-down and the arrays who has 'CL' should be shown on Class Drop-down.So What I did was based on those two identifiers I tried to divide that data into 2 arrays  **fromairportlist=[];** , **flightclass=[];**

Booking Component

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public websiteformdata=[];
  public flightclass=[];
  public fromairportlist=[];

  constructor(private flightService:FlightService, private router: Router) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadFormData();
  }

  loadFormData(){
    this.flightService.getWebSiteFormData().subscribe(data=>this.websiteformdata=data,error=>console.error(error)) 
   
   for (let item of this.websiteformdata) {
     if(item[1]=='AP'){
       this.fromairportlist.push(item[0]);
     }   
   } 
   console.log(this.fromairportlist)
  }
}
```

Booking.component.html file

```
 <td style="height: 39px; width: 14%;"> 
        <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">Departure</div>
        </div>
       <select class="form-control" id="classtype" name="classtype" [(ngModel)]="booking.classtype">
        <option>{{fromairportlist[0]}}</option>
        <option>{{fromairportlist[1]}}</option>
        <option>{{fromairportlist[2]}}</option>
       </select>
       </div>
    </td>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working nothing is displayed on the drop-down as shown on the figure

[image: Drop down]

Please suggest a way to correct it if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First use `*ngFor`: `<option *ngFor="let option of fromairportlist">{{ option }}</option>`

this can be helpful
[Angular 4 setting selected option in Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000950/angular-4-setting-selected-option-in-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Since your result is a string array, loop it through a for loop. Simply,

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let item of fromairportlist">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

If any doubts, see the stackblitz solution for your ref.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2kfec