# Can't bind to 'ngSelected' since it isn't a known property of 'option' - Angular 14

Tags: html, angular, forms, html-select

I have a `select` with an option im trying to auto-select.

Here is the HTML

```html
<select class="form-select" formControlName="role">
    <option *ngFor="let r of this.roles" [value]="r.id" [ngSelected]="test">{{r.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have tried `[ngSelected]` `ng-selected` `ngSelected` `[selected]`, but nothing works.

Here are my versions for angular:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.5
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.5
@schematics/angular             14.0.5
rxjs                            7.5.6
typescript                      4.7.4
```

Comment: I think that `ngSelected` is for angularjs, nor angular.

Comment: Is there an alternative ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 setting selected option in Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000950/angular-4-setting-selected-option-in-dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
In my code, I was using the `[value]` with the `[selected]`

I removed the `[value]` and now the `[selected]` works.

```
<option *ngFor="let r of this.roles" [selected]="this.user.role.id == r.id">
    {{r.name}}
</option>
```