# I need help in approach for making my Angular dynamic form more dynamic

Tags: angular

I have been into Angular and this site really helped me in building an application. I have built a dynamic form in angular with JSON data, where it creates a form dynamically with different controls, validations, properties etc. However, i want to make it even more dynamic, for example one of the control type is say "Picklist" in the json, in this case i want to create a dropdown and pull values from DB and bind it with Dropdown control. Assuming that i already have APIs.
Question is, how to make store the dropdown values dynamically across the application.

I want it to be dynamic, say suppose in my JSON i have 2 picklist dropdown, Country and State for which the values will be fetched from API. I need to dynamically call the respective APIs and store the array of values somewhere to load when the form loads right. In this case i think i have to use Array and to make the subscribe method non Async so that i can store the values in respective Array index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 setting selected option in Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000950/angular-4-setting-selected-option-in-dropdown)

Comment: Not really. i am not looking to bind the values to dropdown, how to make it dynamic based on the value present in JSON. i want it to be dynamic, say suppose in my JSON i have 2 picklist dropdown which has to fetch values from API, say Country and State. I need to dynamically call the respective APIs and store that values somewhere to load when the form loads right

Answer (score 0):

i think you can pass api endpoint to your dropdown component, in dropdown components init function you can fetch data and set the dropdown options, of course you need to set a standart model for dropdowns value and label like; { value: 1, label: "apple" }

if you cant set a standart you can get valueField and labelField as Input

Comment: i want it to be dynamic, say suppose in my JSON i have 2 picklist dropdown which has to fetch values from API, say Country and State. I need to dynamically call the respective APIs and store that values somewhere to load when the form loads right.