# How to highlight the option selected in <ng-select> and <ng-option> tag in angular 5

Tags: html, angular

I have 2 tags, when I click on the drop panel it gives various options to select, by default one value is selected but when I open the drop panel it is not highlighting the previously selected option.

I tried adding `[selected]="filters"` or `[ng-selected]="filters"` in `<ng-option>` tag, but it is giving me error that it is not a known property of `<ng-option>`

How can I highlight this option selected in the drop panel?

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="filterSelected" name="in" id="fileterName" 
       (open)=droppanel() >
    <ng-option *ngFor="let opt of filterJSONData" [value]="opt.val" >
          {{ opt.content }}
    </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how many times you searched it??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968712/angular-2-setting-selected-value-on-dropdown-list
check it out.probably your answer is there.

Comment: @kamolchandraRoy : they are making use of <select> and <option> tag , I am using <ng-select> and <ng_option> tags. that wont help.

Comment: did you try the `[ngOptionHighlight]` directive that is provided with the plugin?  https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#other

Comment: [ngOptionHighlight] is not working @Claies

Answer (score 5):

The definition of the select should be like this:

```
<ng-select
  [items]="filterJSONData"
  bindLabel="{{content}}" bindValue="{{val}}"
  [(ngModel)]="filterSelected">
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
    <div [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{ item.content }}</div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

When you type a text in the select, the matches values are displayed underline.

Comment: It's been split into a different package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-option-highlight