# How to show placeholder (empty option) in select control in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have this code in my template:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedSubSectionId" (ngModelChange)="onSubSectionChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let subSection of event.subSections" [ngValue]="subSection.id">{{ subSection.name }}</option>
</select>
```

In my component:

```
public selectedSubSectionId: any;

public onSubSectionChange(subSectionId: any) {
  // some code I execute after ngModel changes.
}
```

This works ok, but at the beginning I have an empty box. I want to show a placeholder message there. **How can I do this using ngModel?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My solution:

In the component typescript file I add a property selectUndefinedOptionValue that I don't initialize and in the html I add the undefinedSelectOptionValue as value of the placeholder option. This solution works for both number and string model properties.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component-selector',
  templateUrl:'url to template',
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    private selectUndefinedOptionValue:any;
    private someObject:SomeObject;
    
    ngOnInit() {
      someObject = new SomeObject();
    }
}
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="someObject.somePropertyId">
  <option disabled hidden [value]="selectUndefinedOptionValue">-- select --</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">option.text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke MeTTe guys, can anybody explain how this magic works plz? thanks

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome Version 60.0.3112.90 which I'm using to look at the snippet.

Comment: Works on Chrome  60.0.3112.113 with <option [ngValue]=null></option>

Comment: It doesn't work (value or ngValue, undefined or null) with Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 or Version 62.0.3202.75, or Opera.

Comment: <option [disabled]="true" [hidden]="true" [selected]="true">--select--</option> does seem to work (tested on above Chrome builds, plus Opera and Edge. (i.e. 11 doesn't even display my test form!)

Comment: You can slim this down further by putting `undefined` as the value instead of the variable:
`<option disabled hidden [value]="undefined">-- select --</option>`

Answer (score 14):

I've the same question, and i found an example in this great website: [Angular Quick Tip](https://netbasal.com/angular-quick-tip-how-to-show-a-placeholder-in-select-control-bab688f98b98)

also, i put the example below:

```
// template
<form #f="ngForm">
  <select name="state" [ngModel]="state">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Choose a state</option>
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">
      {{ state.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>

//component
state = null;

states = [
  {name: 'Arizona', code: 'AZ'},
  {name: 'California', code: 'CA'},
  {name: 'Colorado', code: 'CO'}
];
```

Also works with Reactive Forms, that's what i'm using:

```
// template
<div class="form-group">
  <select formControlName="category">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Select Category</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" 
            [ngValue]="option">{{option.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

// component
options = [{ id: 1, label: 'Category One' }, { id: 2, label: 'Category Two' }];

form = new FormGroup({
  category: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});
```

Thanks to [Netanel Basal](https://netbasal.com/@NetanelBasal) to provide the answer

Comment: I would recommend adding the `disabled` attribute to the `<option>`.  I've verified this works on IE11.

Answer (score 9):

Add empty option and set to 'undefined' also can be add for null value too

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="barcode">
  <option value="undefined" disabled selected hidden>Select</option>
  <option value="null" disabled selected hidden>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let city of turkiye" [ngValue]="city.id">{{city.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Caution: Safari and IE11 will show two entries with this solution!

Comment: How about `<option [value]="undefined || null" ...`

Comment: @B2K I had hoped this would work in Angular 11, but it does not...

Comment: Another option might be to initialize your model variables, so that they are all defined, thus barcode would be either '' or null but not undefined.

Answer (score 6):

try this code:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedSubSectionId? selectedSubSectionId : ''" (ngModelChange)="onSubSectionChange($event)">
   <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Placeholder</option>
   <option *ngFor="let subSection of event.subSections" [value]="subSection.id">{{ subSection.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think this relies on Bootstrap and wouldn't work without it!?

Answer (score 0):

### This did the trick for me:

`<option` [selected]="true" `value="">Please select</option>`

1. Add an `option` tag ` with Please select as the content.
2. Add a `[selected]="true"` attribute.
3. Add `value = ""` as an attribute.

Without `value=""` the content is not shown until you click on the select field.

### For those using Bootstrap 4+

You can change `[selected]="true"` to `selected`.

`<option` selected `value="">Please select</option>`