# Keep select field placeholder on form.reset() in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41303715/6676148) link helped me to use placeholder in select box. 
So my code is

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm" class="form-sample form-position">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Membership</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select name="membership" [(ngModel)]="membership" class="form-control" required>
      <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected hidden> Please select one option </option>

      <option>Free</option>
      <option>Professional</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">State</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select [(ngModel)]="state" class="form-control" name="state" required=""
          placeholder="Select">
          <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected hidden> Please select one option </option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of statesList">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="text-center container-fluid form-group">
     <button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-fw text-center">Submit</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-fw" (click)="form.reset()">Clear</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is a small part of my code. The above code is working perfectly fine. When the page loads for the select field `Membership` default option `Please select one option` is selected.

But the problem is when i reset the form the text `Please select one option` also gets cleared. But I want this default option to remain selected after the form get reset. to reset the form I use `form.reset()`.

Comment: what is `form.reset()` doing?

Comment: To reset the form we just need to call the function reset() on our myform model.
`#form="ngForm"` i had used it in the form tag. So `form.reset()` will reset the form

Comment: how is `myform model` defined?

Comment: I have added few more lines with form definition in my question. Have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form.reset()` sets `null` values to underlying models. since your assign `undefined` as value to default options, they doesn't match. either provide a custom logic for clearing the form and set model values to `undefined` on reset;

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-fw" (click)="clearForm()">Clear</button>
```

and in your component.ts

```js
clearForm() {
  this.membership = undefined;
  this.state = undefined;
}
```

**OR**

change you option values and initial values of corresponding models to `null`

```html
<option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected hidden> Please select one option </option>
```

and in your component.ts

```js
membership = null;
state = null;
```

here is a demo for second one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngvh9p

Comment: When i  am setting membership or state to null, the default text `Select one option ` is not visible even at the time of page load, i.e for the first time also its not visible.

Comment: you have to assign their initial values to `null` as well, for default values to be selected on first load. it is done exactly like that in the demo above.

Comment: `membership = null;` and `state = null;` when you first define them in your ts file.

Comment: I did the same. and in this case ,`Select one option` is not visible in the view

Comment: did you set `[ngValue]="null"` in your html? like `<option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected hidden> Please select one option </option>`

Comment: Yesh.. its worked.. Thanks .. I was missing this part.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the value in the select, you need to set the value of `membership` to `undefined` when the form is reset. I don't know what `form.reset()` does, but it might set the value to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue.

Opening the page in a new tab showed the **placeholder/default** value on initial loading then leaving the page and returning, it was blank.

I had to add `[ngValue = "null"]` and also set the value in my model initially to **'null'**.

Only after that it showed up.

Buggy code:

```
<select name="title" [(ngModel)]="model.title">
    <option selected disabled> PLACEHOLDER </option>
    <option *ngFor="let title of titles" [value]="title"> title </option>
</select>
```

In component.ts initial value was set to `model.title = ''`, which is 'undefined'.

Fixing the code was through adding the explicit `ngValue` and setting it to 'null':

```
<select name="title" [(ngModel)]="model.title">
    <option [ngValue]="null" selected disabled> PLACEHOLDER </option>
    <option *ngFor="let title of titles" [value]="title"> title </option>
</select>
```

and also setting the initial value of `model.title = null`.

Comment: Consider adding a code example to improve your anwser